# How to mark checked for the values that are recievd from api into checkbox in VUEJS

Tags: html, vuejs2

I am learning VUEJS recently. I cannot move further as i am stuck in an issue.
ISSUE:

i am getting a list from an api call.
Here is the section of code for this:

```
           <b-form-checkbox-group
              v-model="authorize"
              :options="authorize"
              name="authorize"
              stacked
              text-field="name"
              value-field="id"
            >
```

I am getting this using `.get('/authorize')` and i have these values:

```
[{"id":"country:list","name":"country:list"},{"id":"country:create","name":"country:create"},{"id":"user:retrieve","name":"user:retrieve"},{"id":"user:update","name":"country:update"},{"id":"country:destroy","name":"user:destroy"}]
```

In another form i have added some of these value and in response, i get these values

```
[{"id":"country:list","name":"country:list"},{"id":"country:create","name":"country:create"},{"id":"user:retrieve","name":"user:retrieve"}]
```

i get these response using this:

```
          <b-form-checkbox-group
              v-model="authorize"
              :options="currentTutorial.authorize"
              name="authorize"
              stacked
              text-field="name"
              value-field="id"
            >
```

But what i want now is that i want to display all the `authorize` list along with the save items but those saved items should be checked which i am getting from `currentTutorial.authorize` here

Appreciate your help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b-form-checkbox-group
              v-model="authorize.id"
              :options="authorize"
              name="authorize"
              stacked
              text-field="name"
              value-field="id"
            >
```

can you change v-model variable liked as this

Comment: okay i tried this ```<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="authorize.id" :options="currentTutorial.authorize" name="authorize" stacked text-field="name"
              value-field="id">```.  but it only displays the saved ones without checked and if make the options like this ``` :options="authorize"``` it gives all the list